# Load div content on show in a tabbed page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I've made a tabbed web page with a switch using jQuery. The tab switch works nice, but now what i want to achieve is to dinamically load div content with AJAX only when the user clicks on a tab for the first time. I've though of putting a flag as an attribute on tab content div, something like `data-loaded="0"` so that when a user clicks for a second time on the same tab, the data isn't loaded a second time. But what's the best way to dinamically load the data into the div? I'd like to make it general so that the JS (jQuery) function to load data can change for each tab.

Below i've put the code snippet

If someone wants to play with it i've loaded in jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ofwvr0hq/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
  
  $('ul.tabs li').each(function () {
   var nimg = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
   $(this).find('img').attr('src', nimg.replace('_r', '_g'));
  });
  
  var img = $(this).find( 'img' ).attr('src');
  $(this).find( 'img' ).attr('src', img.replace('_g', '_r'));
 });
});
```

```css
ul.tabs{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}
ul.tabs li{
 line-height: 24px;
 background: #ededed;
 color: #777;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 40px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font: 16pt arial,verdana !important;
 border: 1px solid rgb(164, 162, 162);
 border-right: medium none;
 margin-right: -5px;
}

ul.tabs li.current{
 background: none;
 color: rgb(227,32,46);
 border-bottom: 0;
 border-top: 3px solid rgb(227,32,46);
 padding-top: 8px;
}

.tab-content{
 display: none;
 padding-top: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current{
 display: inherit;
}

ul.tabs > li > img {
 margin-right: 5px;
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
}

.tabLast {
 border-right: 1px solid rgb(164, 162, 162) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li data-tab="tab-1" class="tab-link"><img style="float:left;" src="http://fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png"> Amministratore</li>
  <li data-tab="tab-2" class="tab-link current"><img style="float:left;" src="http://fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_r.png"> Letture</li>
  <li data-tab="tab-3" class="tab-link"><img style="float:left;" src="http://fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png"> Unità immobiliari</li>
  <li data-tab="tab-5" class="tab-link tabLast"><img style="float:left;" src="http://fantamondi.it/silcam/images/pencil_g.png"> Riparti</li>
 </ul>

 <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">TAB 1</div>
 <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content current">TAB 2</div>
 <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">TAB 3</div>
 <div id="tab-5" class="tab-content">TAB 4</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've done quite a good job so far. And now, to dynamically load Data to the Div you have a couple of options. You could use Ajax and data-loaded like you said or you declare a Global Boolean Variable and initialize it to FALSE. And then when data is loaded for the First Time, you set it to True. You could then use this Boolean Flag in your AJAX. If the Flag is False, then AJAX Fires, otherwise, nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery .load(). Basically, you would have a page with the div's with the content you want per page and just load that id when the tab is clicked.

Ex:

```
$("#tab-container").load( "ajax/tabs.html #tab-1" );
```

Also see: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: But in this way each time that the user clicks on a tab, the tab content is loaded. I just want it to be done once.